# How to continuously get counter values with F# WMI type provider

Tags: f#, type-providers

Hi I'm trying out F# WMI type provider code sample looks like this

```
type Local = WmiProvider<"localhost">
let data = Local.GetDataContext()
let memory = [for d in data.Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory -> d.AvailableBytes]
```

memory in this case is System.Nullable list. So the question is how to get continuous updates for this list? Currently my code looks like this

```
let printMemory () = 
    let rec outerLoop = 
        let memory = [for d in data.Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory -> d.AvailableBytes]
        let rec loop (values:Nullable<uint64> list) =  
            Thread.Sleep(1000)
            match values with
            |[] -> printfn "empty"
                   outerLoop
            |h::t -> printfn "value = %d" h.Value
                     loop t
        loop memory
    outerLoop
```

So I have to request new list (memory) every time, is this correct approach?
For example PerformanceCounter counter from System.Diagnostics implements NextValue, is there something similar for WMI type provider? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to block the current thread, [Rx](http://reactivex.io/) provides a nice API for handling that:

```
// nuget FSharp.Management
#I "packages/FSharp.Management/lib/net40"
// nuget System.Reactive
#I "packages/System.Reactive.Core/lib/net46"
#I "packages/System.Reactive.Linq/lib/net46"
#I "packages/System.Reactive.Interfaces/lib/net45"

#r "System.Management.dll"
#r "FSharp.Management.WMI.dll"
#r "System.Reactive.Core.dll"
#r "System.Reactive.Interfaces.dll"
#r "System.Reactive.Linq.dll"

open FSharp.Management
open System
open System.Reactive.Linq
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
open System.Text

[<DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)>]
extern int64 StrFormatKBSize(int64 qdw, [<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)>] StringBuilder pszBuf, int cchBuf);

let bytesToString byteCount = 
    let sb = StringBuilder(32);
    StrFormatKBSize(byteCount, sb, sb.Capacity) |> ignore
    sb.ToString()

type Local = WmiProvider<"localhost">
let memory = Local.GetDataContext().Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory
let freeMem() =
    // I don't know the semantics of Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory
    // you might want to adjust the following
    memory
    |> Seq.choose (fun d -> d.AvailableBytes |> Option.ofNullable)
    |> Seq.exactlyOne

let print m =
    printfn "At %A: free %s" DateTime.UtcNow (bytesToString(int64 m))

// Immediately start to produce values every 1 second (on thread pool)
Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds 1.0)
|> Observable.map(fun _ -> freeMem())
// only propagate a value if it differs from the previous one
|> Observable.DistinctUntilChanged
|> Observable.subscribe print

// Causes a non-fatal error in VS Interactive, works in FSI
Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

This script produces e.g.

> At 27.09.2016 10:24:10: free 8'053'600 KB
>   At 27.09.2016 10:24:11: free 8'053'604 KB
>   At 27.09.2016 10:24:13: free 8'053'600 KB
>   At 27.09.2016 10:24:14: free 8'053'604 KB
>   At 27.09.2016 10:24:15: free 8'054'472 KB
>   At 27.09.2016 10:24:16: free 8'054'468 KB
>   At 27.09.2016 10:24:17: free 8'054'496 KB
>   At 27.09.2016 10:24:18: free 8'054'480 KB
>   At 27.09.2016 10:24:20: free 8'054'492 KB

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make call explicitly for new values or use refresh object `WmiSmoObject.Refresh`

```
F#
abstract Refresh : unit -> unit 
override Refresh : unit -> unit
```

Comment: WmiSmoObject is part of  Microsoft.SqlServer.Management which I'm not trying to monitor. I'm already doing explicit call for updated every scan cycle, just wanted to know if it's possilbe to subscibe to updated